# Multidependent dropdown with multiselect

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create multi dependent drop-down list( 3 dependent Dropdown ). I am able to create using data validation using formula `=INDIRECT()` But I am able to apply it for only one cell rather then I want to apply it for a range or for whole column. I want to use Macro(Vba code) to achieve this scenario.
Let say First drop-down contains **Countries** and second dependent dropdown contains **States** and third dependent dropdown contains **Cities** and the Cities dropdown should be multi select with **","** seperation. I am able to achieve this using **data list and formulas** But i want to create it using VBA code. I want to give dropdown list in code itself and apply each dependent dropdown for range(column).

[Click to view Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5We1o.png)

[Click to view Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b7Ko.png)

[Click to view Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCDjU.png)

[Click to view Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vZ5R.png)

Comment: Please include what you have tried in your question, and the problem you had getting it to work.

Comment: Are you working in Excel? Can you show us, at least, a picture of what you obtained using "data list and formulas"? What kind of 'dropdown' are you referring at?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot that I have made in excel using data list formula. I have created the dropdown for single row , But I want it using VBA code (macro). In that code I want to give range for dropdown and lists for dropdown, and want to achieve multi selection for cities dropdown with "," seperation

Comment: What you did using List Validation can be done in VBA, but List Data Validation **does not allow multi selection**. In fact, talking about *with "," seperation*, what do you mean by "Cities dropdown should be multi select"? To only have a cities list, or really to be able to select more then one option (which is not possible)?

Comment: I want to select multiple cities names from cities Drop-down

Comment: This is what I am telling you (also above): It is not possible to select more then one option! But, what do you want saying by "select with "," separation"? This is a concept which does not have a meaning related to selection. At least, unknown by me...

Comment: [Link](https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/ ) look at this link what i mean to say

Comment: This is not a multiselection! This uses Worksheet_Change event in order to set the cell value using its previous value plus the **new selection**, separated by something. If this is what you want, why don't you use the code in the link you show us?

Comment: I can't use that code that code is for single dropdown. But here the scenario is different here I have 3 dependent dropdown.

Comment: And so, what? You were talking about this pseudo multi selection only for one of them. Isn't it true? You must only adapt the code to work for the cell where your Cities (if I remember well)) exist. But, probably, the code must be modified to not allow selecting of the same city (by mistake) more times...

Comment: Yes that's true ! I want multi selection only for cities column. But, I am able to create the  dependent dropdown using data list validation. But I Want to create it using VBA code .If that's done then I will try to apply the link code .

Comment: Did you try something on your own? VBA, I mean...

Comment: Is it any difference between Countries and States? I cannot see any...

Comment: Still alive? Is it any difference between Countries and States? I started creating a piece of code, but if you do not clarify the issue in some minutes, I cannot continue.

Comment: No there is no difference in both of them

Comment: OK. I will finalize the code. It will work on a sheet like your first picture, but, please delete column A:A, which does not have any  meaning. The merge cells "States" contain all the necessary information on their columns.

Comment: Please, test the code and send some feedback,

Comment: If there is any code involved, please **share the code**. Usually, the best way to share code is to add it in text form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next approach, please:

1. Copy the next code in a standard module. It will create (In cell "G1") the first Validation (States/Countries):

```
Sub CreateValidationTest()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, strMerge As String, statesList As String
 Dim lastColLet As String
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet to be processed
 Set rng = sh.Range("G1") 'use here the range where you need to create the Validation
 
 If Range("A1").MergeCells Then 'check if "A1" is part of a merged cells area
    strMerge = Range("A1").MergeArea.Address
 Else
    MsgBox "No merge cells starting with ""A1""!": Exit Sub
 End If
 
 'create states list:_________________________________________________________________
  lastColLet = Split(strMerge, "$")(3)
  statesList = Join(Application.Index(Range("A2:" & lastColLet & 2).Value, 1, 0), ",")
  '___________________________________________________________________________________
  
 With rng.Validation 'create Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                   Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=statesList
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
 End With
End Sub
```

2. Copy the following event in the sheet module where the data to be processed exists (right click on the sheet name -> View code):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim rngDV As Range, oldVal As String, newVal As String
 Dim arr As Variant, El As Variant

 If Target.count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler
 If Target.Address(0, 0) = "G1" Then
    'create the second validation
    Dim stCell As Range, lastRow As Long, listValid As String
    Set stCell = rows(2).Find(what:=Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If stCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    lastRow = cells(rows.count, stCell.Column).End(xlUp).row
    'Debug.Print Range(stCell.Offset(1), cells(lastRow, stCell.Column)).Address: Stop
    listValid = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(Range(stCell.Offset(1), cells(lastRow, stCell.Column)).Value, 0, 1)), ",")
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Range("H1").Validation 'create the second Validation for Cities
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                       Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=listValid
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Range("H1").Value = ""
 ElseIf Target.Address(0, 0) = "H1" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target.Value: Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value: Target.Value = newVal
    If oldVal <> "" Then
      If newVal <> "" Then
         arr = Split(oldVal, ",")
         For Each El In arr
            If El = newVal Then
                Target.Value = oldVal
                GoTo exitHandler
            End If
         Next
         Target.Value = oldVal & "," & newVal
         Target.EntireColumn.AutoFit
      End If
    End If
 End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

How to be used:

a. You firstly must run the `CreateValidationTest` `Sub` and then play with its validation list.

b. You must know that the first validation will be created in "G1" and the second one in "H1". The code will not allow to select an already existing item (in the string separated by comma).

Comment: @Bhushan Agrawal JSR: This only means that you did not activate the sheet to be processed (or not adapt the code with your sheet instead of `ActiveSheet`), or you did not delete the first column (A:A) as I said in my comment, or you really do not have merge cells for "State" area ("A1:D1" - in your picture example). What from above possibilities match your case?

Comment: @Bhushan Agrawal JSR: If you run the code in discussion with the sheet to be processed activated, no need to modify anything in code. Just take care to have the cells before the states name merged. Where it is written "States". The code automatically calculates how many columns are in the merged area and adapts itself in case of adding other states.

Comment: I run the Code and the code is working Perfect But, I said I want three Dropdown one is for Countries name  selection - Russia, Canada, India, United States . Second dropdown is for state selection when I select Russia I want another option - Adygea
, Altai, Dagestan, Buryatia this are the states name, when i select one of the state then I want another third dropdown which will contain cities name of that selected state.

Comment: In my pic I have shown only one example of cities name of Russia country, But the data is large want to add all remaining three countries cities name How should do that ??

Comment: Can it be possibe to add the lists of all dropdowns into `Formula1:= ` or I have to keep all the record of all data in sheet. ??

Comment: I have updated the Screenshoot  1.

Comment: I asked you if Countries and States are the same (they were the same in your picture) and **you confirmed that**. I must confess that I cannot understand your 'updated' Screenshoot 1, in terms of range where to extract the necessary data. If you know exactly where to extract it, te mecanism to be used should be exactly the one used in my code. Try it and if it does not work as you want, start another question where to post the existing code, place relevant picture and accurately explain what is to be done. If you tag me and I will be available, I will try helping you for solving the problem.